# users can not do su to other LDAP user

Tags: debian, su, ldap

I 'm thinking my authentication is working well and PAM is configured on my Debian server because  :

- If I do a ssh connection with a LDAP user it's working with password
- If I do a ssh connection with a No LDAP user it's working with password
- If I do a su from an other ldap user to root user  it's working with password
- If I do a su from an other No ldap user to root user  it's working with password
- If I do a su from root to ldap user it's working without password

My black point is 
If I do a su from a user to a LDAP user it's not working

```
:~$ su -l users
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Here common-account file

```
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 69999 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

Here common-auth file

```
auth    sufficient      pam_unix.so #nullok_secure
auth    requisite       pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 70000 quiet
auth    sufficient      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth    required        pam_deny.so
```

Here common-session file

```
session required        pam_unix.so
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0027
session optional        pam_ldap.so 
session optional        pam_umask.so umask=0027
```

Here common-password file

```
password  requisite   pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3 dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 ocredit=-1
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure md5
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=60001 md5 try_first_pass
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
```

What'm I missing?

Comment: Please include the output of `getent passwd users` and `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf`.